# Bring a PSU from US to Mexico

Tags: electronic-items

I'm going to travel to the US for a couple days and buy a PSU(power supply unit) for a desktop and would like to know if any of you have already done that.

My plan is to bring it with my carry-on luggage in a plastic bag and put it under the seat; The PSU box is about the same as a shoe box (25cm x 20cm x 30cm).

Do you think that's feasible? Will I be allowed to embark a PSU as carry-on luggage?

I'm going on Delta Airlines, if that matters.

Comment: But what's your question?

Comment: If anyone has already done that and if there is anything special or something like that, it's my first time doing this so I have no idea really how does it work.

Answer (score 1):

I would leave it outside of your carry-on when going through security just like laptops etc. If you are saying it would already be separate, in a plastic bag, should not be an issue.